# how to extract the plugin declarations to another file?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Using Gradle 7.5.1, I would like to declare all my plugins in one file, and then `apply` from that file in my main `build.gradle.kts`. Something like this:

./gradle/plugins.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    id("net.researchgate.release") version "3.0.2" apply false
    id("com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin") version "2.1.5" apply false
}
```

and then in build.gradle.kts:

```
apply(from = "${project.projectDir.path}/gradle/plugins.gradle.kts")

allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "net.researchgage.release")
    apply(plugin = "com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin")
    ... etc.
```

A bit of background, I'm trying to extract all common build components shared by different repositories, so I can `git submodule` those shared scripts across the board. The goal is to factor out all the common stuff in a centralized repository that can be reused.

The error message is as follows:

> The plugins {} block must not be used here. If you need to apply a plugin imperatively, please use apply() or apply(plugin = "id") instead

Answer (score 0):

OK, found it. First, the `plugins.gradle.kts` must be applied from `settings.gradle.kts`. Second, this works (main gradle build script):

```
plugins {
    id("net.researchgate.release")
    id("com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin")
}

allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "java")
    apply(plugin = "java-library")
    apply(plugin = "maven-publish")
    ... etc.
```

But this doesn't:

```
allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "java")
    apply(plugin = "java-library")
    apply(plugin = "maven-publish")
    apply(plugin = "net.researchgate.release")
    apply(plugin = "com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin")
    ... etc.
```

No idea why...

Comment: Where do you specify the plugin versions in this solution?